# document.write clear all controls of page

Tags: javascript

document.write clear all controls of page
HI'
when the document.write be run, all controls in the web pages will be clear . why? In asp file

Comment: you need to add more detailed information about the problem you are facing

Comment: Yaou can't use document.write in an existing HTML-page. If you need to insert new things, use the DOM-methods, or do it in the HTML from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use innerHTML of say a div to write.

```
<div id="iwanttowritemore"></div>
```

Then in JS:

```
document.getElementById("iwanttowritemore").innerHTML = "i can write without clearing the page"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `document.write` after the page has loaded, it'll replace the entire page with the contents of said function. Use something else like `innerHTML` if you need to insert content after the page loads. `document.write` is kinda frowned upon anyways.